# Alternatives to Convex Hull or pointcloud to mesh processing

Tags: java, processing, convex-hull, kinect

I'm trying to wrap my head around rendering point clouds.  Right now I'm using Processing/Java, and have a pseudo working thing using QuickHull 3D, but it's not what I've been looking for, effect wise.

This is a sample of what I have: http://vimeo.com/17509829
Here's the javadocs for Quickhull3D: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lloyd/java/doc/quickhull3d/index.html

The Convex hull method is effective for identifying a bounding type of mesh, but not what I'm looking for, which is closer to a "shrink wrap" effect.  I had hoped that I might be able to limit the distance two vertices might be joined by the QuickHull3D, but no go. Long story short, what's happening is this: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/convex-hull.shtml

And I want to be able to identify that the G is a G, however crudely.

Can anyone recommend a different approach for tackling this, a second step that I'm missing/unaware of, or alternatively, a way of actually limiting the distance for joining those vertecies?  I know that's kinda not the point of the convex hull approach, so I shy from asking that, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an alternative to convex hulls? I'm looking for a similar 'shrink wrap' method with say a min radius of connecting points (though I'm working with 2D data).

Comment: I didn't, really. I did limit the bounds of where they formed, but it was SUPER specific to the installation project I was working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [Alpha shapes](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_3/Chapter_main.html) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Is definitely one of the options, will investigate further.